# How to verify a string in Javascript using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am pretty noob at JavaScript RegExp. I just need to verify whether a string is 4 characters long and contains only caps letters (A-Z). Any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: `^[A-Z]{4}$` should do the job

Comment: You are welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty way, you can easily do it using:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$
```

[image: explanation]

**Snippet**

```html
<input id="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="return check();" value="Check" />
<script>
  function check() {
    var value = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if (/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$/.test(value))
      alert("Passes");
    else
      alert("Failed");
  }
</script>
```

**Shorter Version**

```
^[A-Z]{4}$
```

This uses the quantifiers `{4}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a quantifier as well with a range from `A` to `Z` and start and end position of the line.

```
/^[A-Z]{4}$/
```

**Explanation**

- `/^[A-Z]{4}$/`

  - `^` asserts position at start of the string

    **Match a single character present in the list below**

    `[A-Z]{4}`

    `{4}` **Quantifier** — Matches exactly 4 times

    `A-Z` a single character in the range between A (ASCII 65) and Z (ASCII 90) (case sensitive)
  - `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

`/^[A-Z]{4}$/.test('your_string')`

Example:

```
var str = 'YEAH';
if(/^[A-Z]{4}$/.test(str)) {
    //true
}
else {
    //false
}
```